# remove the navbar and style in my new page redirect. React js Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I try at the click of a button to have a redirect to my game-asteroids page. The problem is that with my current structure I have my navbar and my footer as well as the style which are added on my new page
how could I do to have a redirect on a blank add-in page?
I share with you my `App.js` page where I have my routes.

```js
import './style.css';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Preloader load={load} />

      <div className="App" id={load ? 'no-scroll' : 'scroll'}>
        <Navbar />
        <ScrollToTop />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/resume" component={Resume} />
          <Route path="/game" component={Games} />
          <Route path="/game-asteroids" component={GameAsteroids} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the App() will always render the Navbar no matter where or how it's rendered. You would need to do something like:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
const App = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const atGame = location.pathname.includes('game-asteroids')
  return (
    <div className="App" id={load ? "no-scroll" : "scroll"}>
    {!atGame && <Navbar />}
    <ScrollToTop />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/resume" component={Resume} />
      <Route path="/game" component={Games} />
      <Route path="/game-asteroids" component={GameAsteroids} />
    </Switch>
    {!atGame && <Footer />}
  </div>    
</Router>
  )
}
```

I think that's what you're asking. If not, it should be close enough to get you what you want.

Comment: Very well thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Is it a structural defect on my part to have this kind of problem? and how do I make sure that I also exclude the styles on my asteroid-game route?

Comment: No, it's not a structural defect. React is very open-ended, so don't get caught up if you are doing something the 'exact right' way. Just make it work, and you will learn more and more as you go. Getting a book on React design patterns might help you here. As far as excluding the styles, it shouldn't be something you are worried about. Extra CSS that isn't applied at the current page will have a very minimal performance affect if at all. However, you could scope the CSS into the component using something like styled-components if you'd like. If this helped you, please accept this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove footer only from a specific route, you can use `location.pathname`. It returns the current url path name. And then you can set a condition as below:

```
{location.pathname !== '/game-asteroids' && <Footer />}
```

Try below code :

```
    <Navbar />
    <ScrollToTop />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/resume" component={Resume} />
      <Route path="/game" component={Games} />
      <Route path="/game-asteroids" component={GameAsteroids} />
    </Switch>    
   {location.pathname !== '/game-asteroids' && <Footer />}
```